# Pygame: Passing two player objects to class

Tags: python, pygame

I am a Pygame newbie and am learning as I go. I would like to become familiar with normal Pygame conventions. I would like you Pygame experts go over my code and let me know if there are any places I should modify my code to follow best practice.

The point of the game is to collect as many pills as possible. Yellows are worth 10, reds 20, blue 30 and black 40. First one to reach 15,000 wins. The ships are controlled using ‘wasd’ and ‘updownleftright’. The complete code is posted below.

Some areas of concern I am looking at are the following:

Where I created two separate classes to store the score information. I feel that I could do the same job with one class, but am a bit confused on how that would look since I am using a TextGroup and it needs to be passed both Ship objects on the call to TextGroup.update().

```
class Text(Entity):
    def __init__(self, text, size, color, position, font=None):
        Entity.__init__(self)
        self.color = color
        self.position = position
        self.font = pygame.font.Font(font, size)
        self.text = text
        self.image = self.font.render(str(text), 1, self.color)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.move_ip(position[0]-self.rect.width/2, position[1])


class Mass_Left(Text):
    def __init__(self, text, size, color, position, font=None):
        Text.__init__(self, text, size, color, position, font=None)

    def update(self, ship_left, ship_right):
        self.text = "mass: " + str(ship_left.density-169)
        self.image = self.font.render(str(self.text), 1, self.color)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.move_ip(self.position[0]-self.rect.width/2, self.position[1])


class Mass_Right(Text):
    def __init__(self, text, size, color, position, font=None):
        Text.__init__(self, text, size, color, position, font=None)

    def update(self, ship_left, ship_right):
        self.text = "mass: " + str(ship_right.density-169)
        self.image = self.font.render(str(self.text), 1, self.color)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.move_ip(self.position[0]-self.rect.width/2, self.position[1])
```

Also, here in the method ‘moveShip()’ where I am checking if self.player is ‘left’ or ‘right’. I feel that there should be a way to do this by passing the class a function when the Ship object is created that will take appropriate action and different action depending on whether it’s the right or left ship.

```
def moveShip(self):
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if self.player == 'left' and (key[pygame.K_w] or key[pygame.K_s] or key[pygame.K_a] or key[pygame.K_d]):
            if key[pygame.K_w]:
                self.rect.y -= self.speed
            if key[pygame.K_s]:
                self.rect.y += self.speed
            if key[pygame.K_a]:
                self.rect.x -= self.speed
            if key[pygame.K_d]:
                self.rect.x += self.speed

        # Adjust Player 2 Speed
        if self.player == 'right' and (key[pygame.K_UP] or key[pygame.K_DOWN] or key[pygame.K_LEFT] or key[pygame.K_RIGHT]):
            if key[pygame.K_UP]:
                self.rect.y -= self.speed
            if key[pygame.K_DOWN]:
                self.rect.y += self.speed
            if key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
                self.rect.x -= self.speed
            if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
                self.rect.x += self.speed
```

Same issue here with the method ‘moveInbounds()’

Same issue in the method ‘winGame()’.

The function ‘genRandom’ generates a tuple that contains a random x value for the Pills and a random density value between 1-4. I am using string concatenation, then doing a type conversion, but I’m sure there’s a more straight forward way to generate a random tuple.

```
def genRandom(size):
    xval_density = []

    for j in range(size):
        length = str(random.randrange(0, (WIN_W/2) - PILL_WIDTH))
        stup = '('
        stup = stup + str(length)
        stup = stup +  ", "
        stup = stup + random.choice('1111111111111111111122222334')
        stup = stup + ')'
        tup = literal_eval(stup)
        xval_density.append(tup)

    return xval_density
```

I’m also uncomfortable using so many global variables such as PILL_COUNT and TIMER. So if there is a best practice in that situation, I’d be happy to know about it.

Here's the complete code:

```
import sys, pygame, os, random, math, time

from ast import literal_eval

# Force static position of screen
os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED'] = '1'

# Runs imported module
pygame.init()

# Constants
LEFT = 'left'
RIGHT = 'right'

YELLOW = (255, 255, 0)
RED = (255,0,0)
BLUE = (0,0,153)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

SHIP_WIDTH = 13
SHIP_HEIGHT = 13

PILL_WIDTH = 7
PILL_HEIGHT = 25
PILL_MAX_SIZE = 3000
PILL_COUNT = 0
TIMER = 0

WIN_W = 1200
WIN_H = 670


class Entity(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)


class Text(Entity):
    def __init__(self, text, size, color, position, font=None):
        Entity.__init__(self)
        self.color = color
        self.position = position
        self.font = pygame.font.Font(font, size)
        self.text = text
        self.image = self.font.render(str(text), 1, self.color)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.move_ip(position[0]-self.rect.width/2, position[1])


class Mass_Left(Text):
    def __init__(self, text, size, color, position, font=None):
        Text.__init__(self, text, size, color, position, font=None)

    def update(self, ship_left, ship_right):
        self.text = "mass: " + str(ship_left.density-169)
        self.image = self.font.render(str(self.text), 1, self.color)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.move_ip(self.position[0]-self.rect.width/2, self.position[1])


class Mass_Right(Text):
    def __init__(self, text, size, color, position, font=None):
        Text.__init__(self, text, size, color, position, font=None)

    def update(self, ship_left, ship_right):
        self.text = "mass: " + str(ship_right.density-169)
        self.image = self.font.render(str(self.text), 1, self.color)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.move_ip(self.position[0]-self.rect.width/2, self.position[1])


class Ship(Entity):
    def __init__(self, x, y, player):
        Entity.__init__(self)
        self.win = False
        self.speed = 5
        self.player = player
        self.density = SHIP_WIDTH * SHIP_HEIGHT
        self.old_density = 144
        self.densityIncrease = False
        self.image = pygame.Surface((SHIP_WIDTH, SHIP_HEIGHT)).convert()
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, SHIP_WIDTH, SHIP_HEIGHT)

    def moveShip(self):
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if self.player == 'left' and (key[pygame.K_w] or key[pygame.K_s] or key[pygame.K_a] or key[pygame.K_d]):
            if key[pygame.K_w]:
                self.rect.y -= self.speed
            if key[pygame.K_s]:
                self.rect.y += self.speed
            if key[pygame.K_a]:
                self.rect.x -= self.speed
            if key[pygame.K_d]:
                self.rect.x += self.speed

        # Adjust Player 2 Speed
        if self.player == 'right' and (key[pygame.K_UP] or key[pygame.K_DOWN] or key[pygame.K_LEFT] or key[pygame.K_RIGHT]):
            if key[pygame.K_UP]:
                self.rect.y -= self.speed
            if key[pygame.K_DOWN]:
                self.rect.y += self.speed
            if key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
                self.rect.x -= self.speed
            if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
                self.rect.x += self.speed

    def moveInbounds(self):
        # Keep Ship Movement Inbounds
        if self.rect.y < WIN_H/15:
            self.rect.y = WIN_H/15
        if self.rect.y > WIN_H - self.rect.height:
            self.rect.y = WIN_H - self.rect.height

        if self.player == 'left':
            if self.rect.x < 0:
                self.rect.x = 0
            if self.rect.x > WIN_W/2 - self.rect.width:
                self.rect.x = WIN_W/2 - self.rect.width
        elif self.player == 'right':
            if self.rect.x < WIN_W/2:
                self.rect.x = WIN_W/2
            if self.rect.x > WIN_W - self.rect.width:
                self.rect.x = WIN_W - self.rect.width

    def checkCollisions(self, pillGroup):
        collisions = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, pillGroup, True)
        for key in collisions:
            self.density += key.density

    def grow(self):
        if self.old_density < self.density:
            self.old_density = self.density
            self.rect.width = self.rect.height = math.sqrt(self.density)
            self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (self.rect.width, self.rect.height))

    def update(self, pillGroup):
        # Ship Movement
        self.moveShip()
        self.moveInbounds()
        self.checkCollisions(pillGroup)
        self.grow()

    def winGame(self):
        if self.win:
            if TIMER % 5 == 0:
                self.rect.width += 20
                self.rect.height += 10
                if self.player == 'left':
                    self.rect.x -= 4
                elif self.player == 'right':
                    self.rect.x -= 10
                if self.player == 'left':
                    self.rect.y -= 5
                elif self.player == 'right':
                    self.rect.y -= 5
                self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (self.rect.width, self.rect.height))
                self.density += 378
        else:
            if TIMER % 5 == 0:
                if self.rect.width == 0:
                    pass
                elif self.rect.width > 10:
                    self.rect.width -= 5
                    self.rect.height -= 5
                    if self.density >= 0:
                        self.density -= self.density/3
                    self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (self.rect.width, self.rect.height))
                elif self.rect.width <= 10:
                    self.rect.width -= 1
                    self.rect.height -= 1
                    if self.density > 0:
                        self.density -= 2
                    self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (self.rect.width, self.rect.height))

                if self.density - 169 < 0:
                    self.density = 169

    def check_done(self):
        if self.rect.height > WIN_H*1.5 and self.rect.width > WIN_W * 1.5:
            return False
        else:
            return True


class Pill(Entity):
    def __init__(self, xval, density):
        Entity.__init__(self)
        self.speed = 3
        self.density = density
        self.image = pygame.Surface((PILL_WIDTH, PILL_HEIGHT)).convert()
        self.image.fill(self.setColor(density))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect = self.rect.move(xval, WIN_H/15)

    def setColor(self, density):
        if density == 50:
            return YELLOW
        elif density == 100:
            return RED
        elif density == 150:
            return BLUE
        elif density == 200:
            return BLACK

    def update(self):
        if self.rect.y > WIN_H:
            self.kill()
        else:
            self.rect = self.rect.move((0, self.speed))


def addPill(pillGroup, xvalue, density):
    global PILL_COUNT, PILL_MAX_SIZE, TIMER

    if PILL_COUNT + 1 < PILL_MAX_SIZE and TIMER % 10 == 0:
        pill = Pill(100, density)
        pill2 = Pill(100 + WIN_W/2, density)
        pillGroup.add(pill, pill2)
        PILL_COUNT += 1


def genRandom(size):
    xval_density = []

    for j in range(size):
        length = str(random.randrange(0, (WIN_W/2) - PILL_WIDTH))
        stup = '('
        stup = stup + str(length)
        stup = stup +  ", "
        stup = stup + random.choice('1111111111111111111122222334')
        stup = stup + ')'
        tup = literal_eval(stup)
        xval_density.append(tup)

    return xval_density


def loseGame(left, right):
    if left.density > 1500 or right.density > 1500:
        if left.density > 1500:
            left.win = True
        elif right.density > 1500:
            right.win = True
        return False
    else:
        return True


def main():
    # Initialize variables
    global TIMER, PILL_COUNT

    fps = 60
    pygame.display.set_caption('Pong')
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIN_W, WIN_H), pygame.SRCALPHA)
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    play = game_done = True
    xval_density = genRandom(PILL_MAX_SIZE)

    # Create Game Objects
    ship_left = Ship((WIN_W/4) - (SHIP_WIDTH/2), WIN_H - (SHIP_HEIGHT * 4), 'left')
    ship_right = Ship((WIN_W/1.3) - (SHIP_WIDTH/2), WIN_H - (SHIP_HEIGHT * 4), 'right')
    score1 = Mass_Left("mass: " + str(ship_left.density-1), 40, BLACK, (WIN_W/5, 10))
    score2 = Mass_Right("mass: " + str(ship_right.density-1), 40, BLACK, (WIN_W/1.25, 10))
    vert_partition = pygame.Surface((1, WIN_H))
    hori_partition = pygame.Surface((WIN_W, 1))

    # Create Groups
    shipGroup = pygame.sprite.Group()
    shipGroup.add(ship_left, ship_right)
    pillGroup = pygame.sprite.Group()
    textGroup = pygame.sprite.Group()
    textGroup.add(score1, score2)

    # Gameplay
    while play:
        # Checks if window exit button pressed
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT: sys.exit()

            # Keypresses
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()

        # Update Groups
        shipGroup.update(pillGroup)
        pillGroup.update()
        textGroup.update(ship_left, ship_right)

        # Adding Pills
        addPill(pillGroup, xval_density[PILL_COUNT][0], xval_density[PILL_COUNT][1]*50)

        # Print Groups
        screen.fill(WHITE)
        pillGroup.draw(screen)
        shipGroup.draw(screen)
        textGroup.draw(screen)
        screen.blit(vert_partition, (WIN_W/2, WIN_H/15))
        screen.blit(hori_partition, (0, WIN_H/15))

        play = loseGame(ship_left, ship_right)

        TIMER += 1
        # Limits frames per iteration of while loop
        clock.tick(fps)
        # Writes to main surface
        pygame.display.flip()

    # Gameplay
    while game_done:
        ship_left.winGame()
        ship_right.winGame()

        # Updating
        pillGroup.update()
        textGroup.update(ship_left, ship_right)

        # Adding Pills
        addPill(pillGroup, xval_density[PILL_COUNT][0], xval_density[PILL_COUNT][1]*50)

        # Print Groups
        screen.fill(WHITE)
        pillGroup.draw(screen)
        shipGroup.draw(screen)
        textGroup.draw(screen)
        screen.blit(vert_partition, (WIN_W/2, WIN_H/15))
        screen.blit(hori_partition, (0, WIN_H/15))

        game_done = ship_left.check_done() and ship_right.check_done()

        TIMER += 1
        # Limits frames per iteration of while loop
        clock.tick(fps)
        # Writes to main surface
        pygame.display.flip()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: If this code is working you should ask this on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This question could be suitable for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help), as long as (a) your code works as intended, (b) your code is real code, rather than example code, and (c) your code is included in the body of the question. If you wish for a peer review to improve all aspects of your code, please post it on Code Review.